# In which circumstances is it sufficient to branch on the flow on edges to ensure integrality in VRPs?

Tags: reference-request, vehicle-routing, branch-and-bound

I know that it is common to branch on the flow on arcs to ensure intergrality when solving VRPs, but in which circumstances is valid to branch on the flow on edges instead of arcs? References to papers discussing this are welcome.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on the problem and on the formulation that is used. For example, in the following paper the authors compare different formulations for the CVRP, some of which are defined on arcs and some of which are defined on edges:

- An Exact Algorithm for the Capacitated Vehicle Routing Problem Based on a Two-Commodity Network Flow Formulation. R. Baldacci, E. Hadjiconstantinou, and A. Mingozzi, Operations Research 2004 52:5, 723-738. https://doi.org/10.1287/opre.1040.0111

In general, to justify branching on edges, you need to prove the following: when you obtain your final *edge* solution, you can turn it into a feasible *arc* solution with the same cost. In the case of symmetric VRP this is trivial: just traverse all your edges in the same direction. In the case of CVRP this is already tricky: the multi-commodity formulation, for example, propagates load based on the direction of the arc, so the constraint may not work correctly for edges, making it impossible to convert back into a feasible arc solution.

If it is not justified to branch on edges, but you really want to anyways, there are ways to deal with that. For example, I wrote a paper where we branch on edges to avoid symmetry to make the search more efficient. When an edge solution is found, we try to turn it into an arc solution. If that fails, we add a constraint to eliminate this edge solution, and continue the search.

- Addressing Orientation Symmetry in the Time Window Assignment Vehicle Routing Problem. Kevin Dalmeijer and Guy Desaulniers. INFORMS Journal on Computing 2021 33:2, 495-510. https://doi.org/10.1287/ijoc.2020.0974